# npm install returns 401 Unauthorized - Gitlab NPM registry (private)

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, npm-install

I'm trying to use a npm package stored at **Gitlab npm registry** at a private project.

To publish my package i used:

- **My .gitlab-ci.yml**:

  ```
  image: node:12
  stages:
    - deploy
  deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
      npm config set @{{my-org-name}}:registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{{project-id}}/packages/npm/
      npm config set "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{{project-id}}/packages/npm/:_authToken" '{{my-auth-token}}'
      npm publish
  ```
- Then the publish config at **package.json**:

  ```
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public",
    "@{{my-org-name}}:{{my-package-name}}": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{{project-id}}/packages/npm/"
  }
  ```

This steps creates the package correctly, but when trying to install with `npm i @{{my-org-name}}/{{my-package-name}}` I step with `401 Unauthorized error`.

I assume I'm missing an auth config somewhere, but can't figure out which or where!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am working in a private module, and the only way I have been able to install the package is by setting .npmrc in the root of the project where I want to install the module with content like this:

```
# Set URL for scoped packages.
@{scope}:registry=https://gitlab.yourdomain.com/api/v4/packages/npm/

# Create an environment variable for your GitLab auth token
'//gitlab.yourdomain.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken'="${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"

'//gitlab.yourdomain.com/api/v4/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken'="${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN is a personal token that I had to create on GitLab, under Profile and Access Tokens. I put it in an environment variable.

However, I want to find a way authenticate users without needing to create a personal token; I want people in the company to be able to install the module in an another way, maybe using their GitLab credentials, but I have not seen anything like that...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! After setting .nmprc this way, I got a `npm ERR! code E503
npm ERR! 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable - GET https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in
` - Did you encounter with this error to?

Comment: No, we didn't have that error. Not even when we had the name of the scope wrong. By the way, we moved the project to another group, manage to publish using the name of the previous group as scope, but installing didn't work. We also had problem to run it in Docker with NPM 7 and we had to downgrade to NPM 6...

Comment: I found the error, i was setting the registry to different URLs at gitlab-ci.yml and at package.json!